# Specifying client IP on iperf

Tags: client-server, ip, client

I am trying to study network traffic in my lab. I have 31 computers and would like to use all of them to simulate different traffic conditions. However, instead of logging into all 31 and running a command one by one on each machine, I would like to know if there is a shortcut.

My scenario: I want to investigate the affect on bandwidth when x number of computers are transmitting with a server. I have one server computer, and 30 available clients. Testing with two boxes is easy:

client:  ./iperf -c  -p 
server: ./iperf -s -p

I'm trying to avoid running that client command on 30 computers at once. However, I don't know if iperf allows you to specify a CLIENT ip address...I was hoping I could just write a script and execute all 30 machines from one physical workstation.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I just started using iperf so I may be completely wrong here, but I think the tests need to be initiated by the client... However this is not really an iperf related issue. 
If you have ssh access to all the machines, you could setup a cron job that initiates the test, at different times, which could let you prepare scenarios with different loads and different users.

You could use [clusterssh](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/551) to manage a single window opening connections to multiple machines.

You can find it here on [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/clusterssh/)

Hope it helps, it's kind of a late response.